# Order of a complex number

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, group-theory, complex-numbers

The complex number "$z$" has the same order as $(z^{p}*e)$ where $p$ is a prime and $e$ is a p-th root of unity. What are the possible values for the order of $z$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $n$ is the order of $z$, then $z^n = 1$, and $n$ is the lowest such number.  Moreover, note that
$$
(z^pe)^n = [z^{n}]^pe^n
$$

Comment: Could you go a bit further? I can't really see it yet.

Comment: Could you give the solution for a simple case, say p=3?